# How to write Regex condition for userid which allows alpha digits and some special characters

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

In my mvc4 application I have used regex condition for user id

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9@.]*$", ErrorMessage = "User ID is not valid")]
public string userid{get; set}
```

But its not working properly. My requirement is :-

1) User id can be alpha numeric.

2) Spaces are not allowed.

3) can accept FEW specail characters i.e, @ _ . these 3 are allowed

4) First letter should not start with @ or _ or .

5)First letter can be either digit or alphabet.

can someone correct my regex expression.

Comment: Could you add some instances of userid where it does not work? You didn't add _ in the character class, for instance.

Comment: What language is this exactly?

Comment: you missed the underscore `^[A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9@._]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    EnableClientScript="false" runat="server"
    ID="myregex" ControlToValidate="mytextbox"
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._@]+$"
    ErrorMessage="The input fails to validate against the regular expression"/>
```

Assuming your userid will always have at least two characters, use this, which is nearly identical to yours (you forgot the underscore):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._@]+$
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches an ASCII letter or digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9._@]+` matches one or more ASCII letters or digits, dots, underscores or arrobasses
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string